# Jquery send empty data to Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, python-3.6

Info: i'm using python 3.6 and Django 1.10.6.

I try to send a simple dict to change my number of page, but i don't use a form. So i read many tutorials when they use `XMLHttpRequest` and it's work. But in my situation, i just receive an empty query.

*Template.html:*

```html
<p> You select the page {{ page }} </p>

<ul class="pagination" >
  <li><a href="#" value={{ page|add:"-1" }}>&laquo;</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value=0>1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value=1>2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value=2>3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value=3>4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value=4>5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" value={{ page|add:"1" }}>&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>

<script language="javascript">
    $('ul.pagination li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var val = {
                'page': $(this).attr('value'),
        }

        var page = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/index/', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
        xhr.send(val);
   })
</script>
```

*Views.py:*

```
def index(request): 
    page = request.POST.get('page', 0)  #POST ARE YOU HERE ?
    print('[TEST]', request.POST, page)
    return render(request, "site/index.html",
            {'page': page})
```

When i show my console i always have empty query, so it's normal `page=0`.

Console log:

```
[TEST] <QueryDict: {}> 0
```

I when to receive a dict like `{'page':'1'}` sending by a click on the `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because the [`send()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) accepts many data types, but it does not accept an object.

You could fix your issue by providing a string instead:

```
var val = 'page=' + $(this).val();
```

Note the preferred use of `val()` here.

Alternatively if you want to send the value as JSON, you would need to stringify it manually:

```
var val = JSON.stringify({ page: $(this).val() });
```

Comment: It's possible to format the data sent like a dict ?

Comment: Anything is possible, but the format you need to send depends on what your model binder is expecting.

Comment: A JSON will be perfect.

Comment: Nice explication and you are right `.val()` is more practice than `.attr('value')`